# How do I insert an array at a certain position to another array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to make a custom comments system for my website, but I need help with inserting the comment information to the decoded JSON array and then saving it back to the comments file.

I've tried splitting the arrays and pushing the array, but to no prevail.

```php
<?php
$data = array(
  'username'=> $_GET['username'], 
  'email' => $_GET['email'], 
  'time' => time(), 
  'content' => $_GET['content']);

$file = fopen("post-comments.json", "r");
$fileData = fread($file,filesize("post-comments.json"));
$decodedData = json_decode($fileData, true);
$insertedArray = array_splice( $data, 3, 0, $decodedData );
var_dump($decodedData);
echo("<br>");
var_dump($insertedArray);
?>
```

I expect the output to be, as an example, (when the json is encoded again)

```
{"2": [
  {
    "username":"John Doe", "email":"john.doe@example.com",
    "time":12345,
    "content":"Hello World!"
   }
 ]
}
```

with any other past comments in the file aswell.

Comment: Also show us your existing data, that you want to insert this into. Not sure this should involve any slicing&dicing to begin with though.

Comment: have you tried with simply `array_merge`?

Comment: @04FS The only data right now is `{"2":{}}`

Comment: shouldn't it be `{"2":[]}` instead?

Comment: Not sure `array_splice` works with non-int keys

Comment: @Kaddath Good point.